# Not able to insert data in to AOT (Acclerated Only Table) table in IDAA server

Tags: db2, accelerator

I'm trying to insert few records in to AOT tables from Java. Using DriverManager connection (by setting special register in connection URL) insertion is happening. But when using DataSource connection, INSERT query is getting failed with the below exception.

With the same DataSource connection, SELECT query is working fine for this AOT table.

```
com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.SqlException: DB2 SQL Error: SQLCODE=-4742, SQLSTATE=560D5, SQLERRMC=24, DRIVER=4.24.92
```

I'm able to insert in to AOT from AQT Query tool. Should I add any additional configuration for INSERT query at Java side or DB Server side ? Java code inserting table is given below:

```
@Stateless
@LocalBean
public class MyDLService {

    @Resource(lookup = "jdbc/db2_schema")
    private DataSource dataSource;

    public void insert(Set<Key> keys) {
        try(Connection connection = dataSource.getConnection()) {
            PreparedStatement ps = connection.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO SCHEMA.AOT_TABLE (ID, CPOINT_ID) values (?,?)");
            int count = 0;
            for (Key key : keys) {
                ps.setLong(1, 1);
                ps.setLong(2, key.getPointId());
                ps.addBatch();

                if (++count % 1000 == 0) {
                    ps.executeBatch();
                }
            }
            ps.executeBatch();
            ps.close();
        } catch (SQLException e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }
}
```

Comment: Edit your question to show the java code that performs the insert. Most likely it is facts that you are omitting from your question that are pertitent, especially if the java code is being generated for you. Compare the working and failing jdbc traces to see what's different.  The -4742 reason 6 is "THE STATEMENT CANNOT BE EXECUTED BY DB2 OR IN THE ACCELERATOR" for reason "The cursor is defined as scrollable or is a rowset-positioned cursor." , and more details may be available if you EXPLAIN the statement and look in DSN_QUERYINFO_TABLE.

Comment: Updated the exception stacktrace. I added different one by mistake

Comment: reason code 24 means "The DDL or DML statement cannot be offloaded because the connection to the accelerator server does not allow updates. This problem can occur when a two-phase commit requester (for example, a DB2 for z/OS® requester) connects to a DB2 for z/OS server to offload a DDL or DML statement."

Comment: Learn about XA and two-phase-commit in any good RDBMS book or in your toolchain documentation. Then configure your toolchain appropriately.

Comment: As per the error code, XA Datasource/two-phase commit transaction compliant datasource will not work with AOT DML queries. I tried with DB2ConnectionPoolDataSource. Working fine